# Writing this SQL in Kohana query builder

Tags: sql, kohana

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users INNER JOIN roles_users ON users.id = roles_users.user_id 
WHERE roles_users.role_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

I came this far:

```
DB::select()->from('users')->join('roles_users')
->on('users.id', '=', 'roles_users.user_id')
->where('roles_users.role_id', 'IN', array(1, 2))
```

How can i do GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT(*) in Kohana query builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 
'SELECT users.*
FROM users INNER JOIN roles_users ON users.id = roles_users.user_id 
WHERE roles_users.role_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2'
);

$query->execute();
```

Example:

```
    $results = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 
    'SELECT * FROM
    post_scheduled
    WHERE
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(scheduled)) = DATE(NOW())
    AND
    TIME_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(scheduled), "%H:%i") = TIME_FORMAT(NOW(), "%H:%i")
    AND
    published = 0'
    )->execute()->as_array();

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $id = $result['id'];       
        # ...
    }
```

Query builder... (haven't tested)

```
DB::select()
->from('users')
->join('roles_users')
->on('users.id', '=', 'roles_users.user_id')
->where('roles_users.role_id', 'IN', array(1, 2))
->group_by('users.id')
->having('COUNT(*)', '=', '2');
```

Comment: I get error on COUNT column not found for the Having() for the query builder method. 
The first method is also ok, but i dont know how to handle the results? I cant do ->as_array() after execute() ? So how should i handle the results.. for that?

Comment: @Karem, I haven't tested second one, but should be something like that. I have posted working example I have for first method.

Comment: Try ->having(DB::expr('COUNT(*)'), '=', '2');